# python: It is possible to create 3 subplots (on both axis)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

The following code gives 4 (2x2) plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0,5,1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0].plot(x, x)
ax[0,1].plot(x, x*2)
ax[1,0].plot(x, np.sqrt(x))
ax[1,1].plot(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

I wonder if there is any way to create 3 subplots at the location of the first 3 listed above, while getting rid of the bottom right one (`ax[1,1]`) entirely?
(Eventually looks like one subplot aligns with the x-axis of the main plot, while the other aligns with the y-axis.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subplots` generates all of the subplots even if you don't put anything there. How about using `subplot` instead?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

x = np.arange(0,5,1)
plt.subplot(221).contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.subplot(224).plot(x, x*2)
plt.subplot(223).plot(x, np.sqrt(x))
plt.show()
```

Edit: added contour exmple adapted from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html).

Comment: It's not the type of the plot that matters - it's the division to subplots. Every thing that can work on an [axes](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fapi%2Faxes_api.html&ei=xRLnU--IDoLMyAPXvYH4Aw&usg=AFQjCNEVMB62MzHbi8B5BAGmrMsMddFezA&sig2=PU5Zp56S691KUdF34e04sw&bvm=bv.72676100,d.bGQ) object can work here. I've edited the example.